# Scheduled tasks on multiple instances of spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-kafka, scheduling

I'm developing Spring Boot application with REST interface that will have multiple instances. In the application, there are many schedulers that call another API and store data on application context.

I do not want to call APIs by every single instance. (Having 20 instances will cause 20 calls to API).

I want to call API just once and notify other instances that call has been executed and share/push context to other instances.

What are the possibilities here?

Do the platforms like Kafka, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Redis and generally Java messaging JMS are designed for such use cases?

Comment: Do you mean multiple instances on the same server/VM?

Comment: Maybe [ShedLock](https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring) will be helpful...

Comment: with the problem it is also better to explain requirement